# in-app update is not working app is also live on play store?

Tags: java, android, in-app-update

I am implementing in-app update feature, for that I am using google play core library as `implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.6.1`.
this code always returns no update available.

```
private void checkUpdate() {
    appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);
    Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();
    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AppUpdateInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AppUpdateInfo appUpdateInfo) {
            if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
                    && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {
                try {
                    appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(appUpdateInfo, AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE, SplashActivity.this, 102);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.e("UPDATE", "yes");
            } else {
                goToActivity();
                Log.e("UPDATE", "no");
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: We don't need any permission for this.In app-update will work in beta vesrion

Comment: @SumitKumawat this is not working in beta mode can you help me regard this and do you have any code so i can use?

Comment: Have you fixed this issue @vivekmittal?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your class implement `InstallStateUpdatedListener`

Code snippet:

```
 private var appUpdateManager: AppUpdateManager? = null
        private var appUpdateInfo: AppUpdateInfo? = null

        private val updateAvailable = MutableLiveData<Boolean>().apply {
            value = false
        }


    appUpdateManager?.appUpdateInfo?.addOnSuccessListener {
                    if (it.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE &&
                            it.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)) {
                        appUpdateInfo = it
                        updateAvailable.value = true
                    } else {
                        updateAvailable.value = false
                    }
                }

        appUpdateManager?.appUpdateInfo?.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
                    if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)) {
                        updateAvailable.value = true
                    } else if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS) {
                        if (appUpdateInfo.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED) {
                            onDownloadDone()
                        }
                    }
                }

                updateAvailable.observe(this, Observer {
                    if (it) {
                        pAppUpdate.show()
                    } else {
                        pAppUpdate.gone()
                    }
                })


                pUpdateNowButton.setOnClickListener {
                    if (updateAvailable.value == true) {

                appUpdateManager?.startUpdateFlowForResult(it, AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE, activity, REQUEST_CODE_FLEXI_UPDATE)
                    }
                }
```